# Eloquent hasManyThrough

Tags: php, laravel

I have three table:

`studios, users, programs`

Table programs belongs to user from users, table users belongs to studio.

I want to get all programs from table with id from studio with where clauses for programs.

I have in studio class

`public function programs()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Studio\Program', 'Studio\User')->with('user');
}`

I use

`Studio::programs->where('date', '=', $date)->where('room', '=', $room)`

Laravel get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::where()`

How to get all programs from table programs with a specified studio id?

### Edit

`Studio::find(1)->programs()->where('date', '=', $date)->where('room', '=', $room);` work but all elements is combinated.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by combinated?

Comment: Get tabel program and tabel user together

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$studios = Studio::with('programs' => function($query) use ($date) {
    $query->where('date', $date);
})->where('room', $room)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks but I use joins better.